# Does setting FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING in transformerFactory update other security features as well?

Tags: java, xerces, xalan

In jdk1.6, while I am setting

```
transformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, false)
```

I am facing the following error:

> javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Cannot set the feature 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' on this TransformerFactory.
>           at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.setFeature(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:418)

As with what I found in here : [How to prevent xalan.jar that has META-INF\services\javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory from taking over JDK 1.6 built in Xalan implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447633/how-to-prevent-xalan-jar-that-has-meta-inf-services-javax-xml-transform-transfor)
I cant make the changes suggested here as there will other API conflicts as reviewed by my admin.

And as per this link : http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/features.html#domsource
You can use the `TransformerFactory.setFeature(String, boolean)` method to set the value of a feature. Xalan-Java only supports setting of the `XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING` feature. For all other features, TransformerFactory exposes their values, but cannot change their states.

So it seems we can set only this feature if xalan implementation of TransormerFactory is used.

```
transformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
```

Finally my Question:
if we set feature:

```
transformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
```

Then is the other feature (`XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD`) automatically set to false.
I got the above feature as "false" from the logs I set. 
But I want to know for sure if the `accessExternalDTD` feature will be set to false by default or if the secure-processing feature is set to true.

Answer (score 7):

In Java 8 yes. If we set

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
```

Then the attributes `ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD`, `ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET` are setting to `""` like the [owasp guide](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#transformerfactory) recommends.

We can verify it with:

```
Object hasExternalDtd=factory.getAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD);
Object hasExternalStyle=factory.getAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET);
```

after setting the `FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING` feature.

The default value if we don't set it is `all` for both properties.

Comment: factory.getFeature() worked for me, instead of factory.getAttribute()

Answer (score 1):

From the source it looks like the other **features** are not updated when **XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING** is updated :

```
  public void setFeature(String name, boolean value)
  throws TransformerConfigurationException {

// feature name cannot be null
if (name == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException(
              XSLMessages.createMessage(
                  XSLTErrorResources.ER_SET_FEATURE_NULL_NAME, null));    
}

// secure processing?
if (name.equals(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING)) {
    m_isSecureProcessing = value;           
}
// This implementation does not support the setting of a feature other than
// the secure processing feature.
else
{
  throw new TransformerConfigurationException(
      XSLMessages.createMessage(
        XSLTErrorResources.ER_UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE, 
        new Object[] {name}));
}
}
```

So it looks like I need to find another way to set this feaure **XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD** :(

Comment: Did you find another way?